# onWillAccept and onAccept with multiple DragTargets

Tags: flutter

I have an unknown number of DragTargets and I want to know on which DragTarget the drag object is dropped. All DragTargets have the properties onWillAccept: _onWillAccept and onAccept: _onAccept. Since all the DragTargets are calling the same method, how can I do it?

Comment: "Since all the DragTargets are calling the same method". Each DragTarget will call its `own method`. You can have name/identifier/index to distinguish the targets. And print/store the name/identifier/index on `onAccept`

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks.